# alias the ip address of a system

Tags: linux, java, tomcat

How to alias ip address of a system, I am running an application on a server in a local network but typing ip address in URL in order to access that application doesn't looks good.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to add an entry to the `hosts` file so you can map a name `examplename` to an IP address `192.168.1.10`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file) shows where your host file is likely to be located.

Example:

```
  102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
   38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host
```